# NodeJS - Requiring module returns empty array

Tags: node.js

Writing the simplest module we could, we write into hello.js:

```
var hello = function(){
  console.log('hello');
};

exports = hello; \\ Doesn't work on Amazon EC2 Ubuntu Instance nor Windows Powershell
```

I run Node and require the module

```
var hello = require('./hello');
hello;
```

and an empty array `{}` gets returned when I'm supposed to get `[Function]`.

I tried replacing `exports` with `module.exports`, but this doesn't work on my Windows Powershell. It does work on my Amazon EC2 Ubuntu Instance, so why doesn't `exports` work? Has the API changed? And what could possibly be happening with Powershell that neither of these work?

I know Windows isn't the most desirable development environment, but I can't get my head around such a simple mishap.

Comment: `{}` is not an array, it is an object. `[]` is an array. Technically, `[]` is also an object, as `Array` extends from `Object`, but no matter which way you slice it, `{}` is never an array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason `exports` is not working is because of the reference conflict. The top variable in each file is `module` which has a property `module.exports`. When the module is loaded **new variable** is created in the background. Something like this happens:

```
var exports = module.exports;
```

Obviously `exports` is a reference to `module.exports`, but doing

```
exports = function(){};
```

forces `exports` variable to point at function object - it does not change `module.exports`. It's like doing:

```
var TEST = { foo: 1 };
var foo = TEST.foo;
foo = "bar";
console.log(TEST.foo);
// 1
```

Common practice is to do:

```
module.exports = exports = function() { ... };
```

I have no idea why it doesn't work under Windows Powershell. To be honest I'm not even sure what that is. :) Can't you just use native command prompt?

Answer (score 9):

**EDIT**

exporting with ES6 is a little nicer

```
export const hello = function(){
  console.log('hello');
};
```

importing will look like

```
import {hello} from './file';
```

---

**Original answer**

You'll want to use `module.exports`

```
var hello = function(){
  console.log('hello');
};

module.exports = hello;
```

If just exporting one thing, I'll usually do it all in one line

```
var hello = module.exports = function() {
  console.log('hello');
};
```

---

### Extras

If you **use a named function**, in the event an error occurs in your code, your stack trace will look a lot nicer. Here's the way **I** would write it

```
// use a named function               ↓
var hello = module.exports = function hello() {
  console.log("hello");
};
```

Now instead of showing `anonymous` for the function name in the stack trace, it will show you `hello`. This makes finding bugs so much easier.

I use this pattern everywhere so that I can debug code easily. Here's another example

```
// event listeners          ↓
mystream.on("end", function onEnd() {
  console.log("mystream ended");
};

// callbacks                              ↓
Pokemon.where({name: "Metapod"}, function pokemonWhere(err, result) {
  // do stuff
});
```

---

If you want to **export multiple things**, you can use `exports` directly, but you must provide a `key`

```
// lib/foobar.js
exports.foo = function foo() {
  console.log("hello foo!");
};

exports.bar = function bar() {
  console.log("hello bar!");
};
```

Now when you use that file

```
var foobar = require("./lib/foobar");

foobar.foo(); // hello foo!
foobar.bar(); // hello bar!
```

---

As a final bonus, I'll show you how you can rewrite that `foobar.js` by **exporting a single object** but still getting the same behavior

```
// lib/foobar.js
module.exports = {
  foo: function foo() {
    console.log("hello foo!");
  },
  bar: function bar() {
    console.log("hello bar!");
  }
};

// works the same as before!
```

This allows you to write modules in whichever way is **best suited for that particular module**. Yay!